# How to modify this bar chart in SSRS to have the Y axis labels show up on the right side of the chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

How to modify this bar chart in SSRS to have the Y axis labels show up on the left side of the chart?  The only way I was able to get the Y axis labels to show at all was to select one of the series, choose Series Properties...Axes and Chart Areas, and select Vertical axis: Secondary.  Setting the vertical axis to 'Primary' causes it to not be displayed on the chart in design or preview.

[image: Chart Screenshot]

Suffice to say, in this chart, because of big discrepancies between groups, it is difficult to line up the categories visually when they are on the right side.

Comment: Is this picture what you have so far or what you want it to look like? I'm really unclear on your desired end result.

Comment: The image is what i have thus far; the axis headings on the right I want to move to the left

Comment: I would normally set the series Vertical Axis to Primary to achieve this. After you do that, does a Vertical Axis appear in the SSRS Design view?

Comment: Setting the Vertical Axis to Primary is removing it from display ![Bar Chart with Axis Set to Vertical]http://i.imgur.com/bSoHwE7.gif

Answer (score 1):

Well, for reasons unclear, it appears the chart did not have 'Show Vertical Axis' selected.  This behaved differently than if I selected the Series->Axes and Chart Areas->Vertical axis: and attempted to change the Secondary to the Primary.

[image: SSRS Bar Chart - Show Vertical Axis]

Selecting 'Show Vertical Axis', and deselecting 'Show Secondary Vertical Axis' achieved the desired effect.  Category headings are on the left of the bars in the chart.  It is now easier for the eye to track for both categories with very high or very low values.

[image: SSRS Bar Chart - Vertical Axis on Left]