# ssrs: how to replace vertical axis (Y) from left to right

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, power-bi-report-server

Would you help me please, to replace vertical axis (Y) from left to right.
I've learnt some articles like:
[official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-axis-labels-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491285/how-to-modify-this-bar-chart-in-ssrs-to-have-the-y-axis-labels-show-up-on-the-ri)

but didn't achieve a result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use the secondary axis like this

Right-click one of the bars and select "series properties"

[image]

Then click "Axes and chart Area"
Then Vertical Axis - Secondary
You will see the Axis move to the right. (Actually the primary axis on the left is disabled and the secondary axis on the right is enabled)

[image]

Comment: Alan, thank you very much. First, I tried this, but failed because the second part of my bar remained on the left side. Then I swiched the second part of my bar to secondary axis - it worked.